# What would you call "mouse pad" in Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: português-brasileiro, vocabulário

What would you call "mouse pad" in Brazilian Portuguese?

It is a flat, corrugated surface to improve the use of the computer mouse.

Suggestions: tapete de rato, mouse pad, tapetinho de mouse.

Image: http://www.toshiba.pt/CMS/PT/ProductPictures/bundle_final_4th_August__1_.jpg

[image: a mouse pad]

Comment: pt-PT: Tapete de rato

Comment: /mauzipédi/ :-)

Answer (score 5):

In Brazil we don't have a specific word for *mouse pad*.

Mouse pad will still be mouse pad. Like a lot of words or expressions relative to computing, basically.

For example:

```
wireless, mouse, backend, frontend.
```

A example in a sentence:

```
Ganhei um mousepad quando comprei um novo computador.
```

in english will be like this:

```
I got a mousepad when bought a new computer.
```

All of these examples above are perfectly understood in Brazil. No need to translate them.

These words, usually english words, are called "estrangeirismo", when habits start to accept a foreign word as a native of your language.

Comment: Maximiliano, "mouse", "mouse pad", "download", etc. não são neologismos.  Por enquanto, são "estrangeirismos".  No dia em que incorporarmos tais palavras ao nosso léxico, e adaptarmos a grafia ao modo como a palavra é pronunciada, elas passarão a ser "empréstimos linguísticos".

Comment: There's probably a difference between words like design, layout, even mouse...  And mouse pad,  a noun phrase. I'd be a little surprised if it wasn't tapete de mouse. Certainly there's mainly this phrase in resale pages for individuals like the Brazilian mercadolibre.  There's also a difference between Brazilian pt and European : words like design aren't in fashion in Europe,  this internationalization of pt is mainly Brazilian.

Comment: Acho que esteira fica melhor para pad.

Comment: Maximiliano, can you add an example sentence? I think your answer would be much more solid with one.

Comment: nos dicionários existe leiaute

Answer (score 2):

[É "mouse pad" mesmo](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mouse%20pad%20pre%C3%A7o), ou, menos frequentemente, apoio para mouse ou suporte para mouse.

Comment: Existem outros nomes pouco usados em pt-BR como "apoio para mouse", "base para mouse", ou "suporte para mouse", geralmente quando são modificações do mouse pad tradicional

Answer (score 1):

**Brazilian Portuguese**

Even though it's an object we use every day when we move a computer mouse on its surface, we rarely hear someone mention its name. The only name I've heard so far in Brazilian Portuguese is really **"mouse pad"**, and I don't think I've heard it more than a dozen times.  In written Portuguese, however, we find **"tapete de mouse"** just as often as "mouse pad".  My small sample in the spoken language  doesn't allow me to affirm "mouse pad" is the more prevalent term, though. Then again, who's got a large sample from the spoken language if most people seldom need to use the word?

Answer (score 0):

In Brazil good number of IT related objects keep their English names. In Portugal, however, they typically name them using Portuguese words. For example:

English   l   Brazil    l   Portugal

Monitor   l   Monitor    l  Ecrã

Mouse      l     Mouse    l    Rato

Comment: Curiously, écran ís a French, not a Portuguese word. It is monitor that is Portuguese; it was the English language that borrowed it from Latin.

Comment: In Portugal we use monitor as well.

Answer (score -1):

"Tapete do rato" é o termo correto.

Comment: Nunca ouvi este termo antes. Já ouviste-o sendo utilizado em quais situações? Conversas informais? Escrita?

Comment: É um termo comum em Portugal. Refere sempre ao objecto que está por baixo do rato.